# How do I choose which Subway line maps uses?

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

If I use Apple Maps for transit directions, oftentimes one of the steps will say something like this:

> [image]

If you then tap on the row that says to take the A, C or E trains, you'll be taken to a screen like this:

> [image]

Notice how the previous screen mentioned I could take A, C, or E trains, but this screen only shows me information about a random train it chose, the E train.

How do I change which train it's displaying information for?

For example, I'd like the same level of info about "Upcoming departures" for the A or C trains. However, no matter which element I tap on, or what swipe gestures I try, I can't seem to find a way to get information about one of the other trains.

Is there any way to do this in Apple Maps, or are we stuck with whatever Apple randomly chooses when there are multiple trains that can take you somewhere?

---

**Update**: To be clear, my question should not be confused with the initial screen showing you which route to take. I do see an option to choose many different routes:

> [image]

My question is about once I hit "go" next to the first route in this list, which has options to take 3 different trains, how do I see information about the other 2 trains?

Comment: On my phone, I’m offered several options when different buses cover the same route. Can you try routing from the MSP airport to 111 Hennepin Ave S and see if this is more about the transit provider than a limitation in maps app? I then pick the bus I want if it’s slower.

Comment: @bmike: For some reason when I try to route from/to those destinations, it says "Transit Directions Not Available." However, I updated the question to clarify that I do see a bunch of options to choose between different buses, trains, etc. The problem stems from when one of those options itself has several train lines that all serve the same route. (e.g. this problem would only exist on the first (47 min) and last (50 min) of the 5 routes in the screenshot, since those are the only two that have the A, C, and E options on the last leg of the trip.)

Comment: This feature used to be available. I've filed a bug report as FB9637834

Answer (score 0):

I believe the UI focuses on start time for the trip and duration of the trip when it offers directions. I also use the selection of routes offered to steer a route to a specific train or bus, but there doesn’t see to be any way to lock in a specific bus route or train line on iOS 14 or macOS 11.